# inkscape: An easy way to make a Bezier curve with a white border?

Tags: inkscape

I'd like to be able to draw a black Bezier curve of arbitrary shape which has a white border to it (the centre of the curve being black).  Is there an easy way to do this?

For instance, see the attached image.  It's easy to do what I want for a straight line by just copying the original bezier curve, increasing the width and pasting on top of the original.  But it doesn't quite work as well when there are curves; see the curve in the figure whose left border is thicker than the right.

[image: Examples of Bezier curves with borders. The straight line is what I'd like, a bezier curve with an even white border around it. The left is a naive attempt at doing the same when a curve is involved. The borders don't work out as smoothly.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your stroke to path. It can have different fill and stroke colors:

[image]

Here a wide red stroke is drawn. Its converted to path (Path > Stroke to Path). A black stroke is added like to any closed shape.

If you need open ends, you can add a clipping mask. It's done in bottom line.

Comment: This is great, really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method that might work for you.  This uses the pattern along a path feature.

1. Create a Bézier curve, with a black fill, and white stroke
2. Draw a rectangle with the same fill and stroke, and click Path > Object to path.
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the rectangle to the clipboard

[image]

4. Select the curve, and click *Path > Path Effects*
5. Click the *Add* button, and choose the "Pattern on a Path" Effect
6. Click on the Paste Path button
7. Choose the "Single Stretched" option

[image]

Here's the result, as you can see the Bézier curve is editable

[image]

If you don't like the white border around the ends, you could always employ the clipping mask trick as mentioned by user287001.